# Ideas for interesting Twitter feeds and similar resources to follow for learning Korean?

Tags: resources

[image: https://twitter.com/Engkr_bot]

Just now I stumbled across https://twitter.com/Engkr_bot - it seems to regularly tweet a word or phrase in English and Korean. This seems a great way to drip-feed a bit of Korean learning into busy days.

Are there any other twitter, RSS or other feeds of small snippets that could be similarly useful? They could be 'bots' like this one, or written by a human.

Answer (score 1):

Not really a feed, but the *National Institute of Korean Language's Korean-English Learners' Dictionary* has a [**Korean Word of the Day**](https://krdict.korean.go.kr/eng/mainAction?nation=eng) on their main page.

Answer (score 1):

I hope these links will help :)

[@GrammarGirl_EN](https://twitter.com/GrammarGirl_EN)

[@Living_English](https://twitter.com/Living_English) *(This Twitter account is actually for Koreans who want to learn English but I think it does help the other way around, too.)*

Answer (score 1):

[Talk to Me in Korean](http://www.talktomeinkorean.com) has an [**RSS feed**](http://talktomeinkorean.libsyn.com/rss) of all their videos.